# Will saving in RAW + JPG provide the same IQ result as saving them both separately?

Tags: dslr, raw, jpeg, memory-card

Storage is cheap nowadays, and carrying a few extra SD-cards aint to heavy. Is there a real downside to this option? Besides filling up more memory and some extended loading times?

The question is regarding dSLR cameras (Canon 5D mkII / Canon 600D) but additional information is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest disadvantage of RAW + JPEG is that the camera needs to push more data through its pipeline, so it's slower and the buffer size is smaller. Taking [DPReview's numbers for the 600D](https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos600d/9), but it will be the same for other cameras:

> - RAW: 3.6 fps for 6 frames, then around 0.77 fps. 8 seconds to recover.
> - RAW+JPEG 3.6 fps for 3 frames, then two slower frames followed by 0.5 fps. 8.5 seconds to recover.

In terms of IQ advantages, there's pretty much none. [While it's generally impossible to *exactly* recreate the in-camera JPEG processing from a RAW file](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43400/how-similar-is-in-camera-jpeg-processing-to-own-brand-raw-conversion), you can almost always get close enough that you're not going to be able to tell the difference, so RAW is strictly superior to JPEG in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, to be clear, a better way would be to exclusive shoot in RAW and then run the "not gonna bother to edit these"-photos through a software like Lightroom for jpg-converting, due to the fact that these are going to be "close enough" to what the camera would've done anyways?

Comment: Lightroom may well be further from the camera than the first party RAW converter (i.e. DPP for Canon) - it certainly gives me very different white balance at times, and will definitely give you different results if you use things like Auto Lighting Optimizer.